# localização do usuário pelo IP

Tags: php, ajax, ip, localização

Gostaria de conhecer uma biblioteca php que me ajudasse com a localização do acesso do usuário pelo IP, bom eu achei uma na internet e ate funcionou bem (nao mostrou exatamente a localização) somente ums 50 km de diferença mas pelo menos da pra saber a cidade de acesso! ate aqui blz, porem essa aplicação utiliza o o site http://www.geoplugin.net/ para obter as informações, se, eu carregar a pagina trazendo o ip, mostra os dados perfeitamente mas se eu colocar para trazer as informações na hora em que meu Ajax estiver guardando as informados no banco, ele da erro! nao carrega o link para trazer as info do ip!

Alguém conhece algum outro método? biblioteca ou artigo para me ajudar ? ou melhor alguém sabe me explicar por o php com ajax não carrega o link para as variáveis pelo?

```
echo "Geolocation results for {$geoplugin->ip}: <br />\n".
"City: {$geoplugin->city} <br />\n".
"Region: {$geoplugin->region} <br />\n".
"Area Code: {$geoplugin->areaCode} <br />\n".
"DMA Code: {$geoplugin->dmaCode} <br />\n".
"Country Name: {$geoplugin->countryName} <br />\n".
"Country Code: {$geoplugin->countryCode} <br />\n".
"Longitude: {$geoplugin->longitude} <br />\n".
"Latitude: {$geoplugin->latitude} <br />\n".
"Currency Code: {$geoplugin->currencyCode} <br />\n".
"Currency Symbol: {$geoplugin->currencySymbol} <br />\n".
"Exchange Rate: {$geoplugin->currencyConverter} <br />\n";
```

a classe geoplugin ja carrega o ip altomaticamente entao nao precisa criar variavel para isso, so pedir as infomraçoes

Comment: A única forma de no front-end, com javascript(Ajax) obter dados de um site que possa outro domínio, é se ele disponibilizar dados no formato JSONP.

Comment: O site também pode "declarar" na resposta da requisição que aceita esse tipo de requisição. Mas parece que não é o seu caso. Ainda assim, se possível, posta o código.

Comment: Mas o que não funciona é a requisição ajax? Ou o lado servidor, php?

Comment: Miguel, creio que seja algo do lado do servidor, pois quando tento carregar a pagina ip.php , tudo funciona perfeito, mas quando utilizo o ajax, a pagina ip.php deveria carregar as informaçoes do ip e colocar as variaveis logo em seguida no banco mas ele nao faz isso com ajax, mau humor, eu acho vou tentar trazer os dados via json para ver se da certo, vou tentar postar o scrip para vc ver

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro no console, para confirmar se é um problema de proteção CORS?

Comment: bom pessoal, nao consegui resolver o problema, o solução foi: assim que o usuario carrega pagina, em dois inputs hidden carrega as informaçoes nessesaria, e depois pego essas informaçoes com o ajax

Comment: Eu já usei este bundle configurável pelo composer: https://github.com/aferrandini/Maxmind-GeoIp

Comment: Amigo, eu utilizo o [IP-API](http://ip-api.com/) que é uma ótima biblioteca que retorna em JSON, CSV, XML, aceita requisições AJAX, e aceita até 150 requisições por minuto pelo mesmo IP. Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você já tentou desta forma? com o geolocation....em JS

```
/*início código de geolocalização*/
function GeoLocalizacao() {
    if (navigator.geolocation){//verificando se há suporte para API de     Geolocalização
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSucesso, erro);
    } else {
       $('#status').text('Seu browser não suporta geolocalização!');
    }
}
```

Caso esteja ok.. basta mostrar os dados no map

```
function locSucesso(position) {
var latlngGeo = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); //pegando localização do usuário
var myOptions = {//opções do mapa
    zoom: 15, //configuração da proximidade de visualização do mapa quando iniciado
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //tipo do mapa (ROADMAP --> normal, default 2D map)
    center: latlngGeo
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), myOptions);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title:"Você está aqui!" //texto quando usuário passar mouse por cima do marcador
});
marker.setPosition(latlngGeo);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Você está aqui!' //mostrar texto quando usuário clicar no marcador
});
```

... eu testei enviando os dados através de um form.. ou seja na minha view eu criei um form com campos hidden e com o resultado da geolocalização eu coloquei os valores lat e long (através de jQuery) no form... e com isso pode enviar o form via ajax(json) para a controller e trata-las para envio no banco.